# Accessing a modal viewController from Appdelegate

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

I have a situation where if the user is not logged in to Firebase, when they launch my app, a modal viewcontroller is presented asking them to log in.
I am also using UIActivityViewController to send data between devices, but want to notify the user with an alert if he is not logged in.
I figure I can do this from the AppDelegate in the open url application function:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, ...
```

I just have to figure out how to navigate to that viewcontroller to call the function that will present my alert.
Within this function, I have this:

```
if status == .notLoggedIn {
   guard
   let rootVC = window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController,
   let collectionSplitVC = rootVC.viewControllers?.first as? UISplitViewController,
   let navVC = collectionSplitVC.viewControllers.first as? UINavigationController,
   let MyBookshelfCollectionVC = navVC.children.first as? MyBookshelfCollectionVC

   // here is where I want to get access to the modal viewController presented on this MyBookshelfCollectionVC.
   // it is called LoginVC

   else { return true }
    LoginVC.showAlertFromAppDelegate(status: status)
 }
```

So the question his, how do I access this modal viewcontroller?

Comment: `MyBookshelfCollectionVC.presentedViewController` ???

Comment: Perfect.  Works like a charm.  Thanks Prashant